# Xamarin.Auth - Multiple authentication error popups causing app crash

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Auth and OAuth2Authenticator for login. At times, I am receiving infinite authentication error popups.
From the app center crashlytics, I am receiving the following exception message:
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.

```
JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, 
Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)
JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)
Dialog.Show ()
ActivityEx.ShowError (Android.App.Activity activity, System.String title, System.String message)
ActivityEx.ShowError (Android.App.Activity activity, System.String title, System.Exception exception)
WebAuthenticatorActivity.<OnCreate>b__4_1 (System.Object s, Xamarin.Auth.AuthenticatorErrorEventArgs e)
Authenticator+<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<RaiseErrorEvent>b__0 ()
Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run ()
IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this)
(wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.49(intptr,intptr)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel InputChannel.java:148
android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay IWindowSession.java:804
android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView ViewRootImpl.java:737
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView WindowManagerGlobal.java:359
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView WindowManagerImpl.java:94
android.app.Dialog.show Dialog.java:330
mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run RunnableImplementor.java:30
android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread Activity.java:6201
mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run RunnableImplementor.java:30
android.os.Handler.handleCallback Handler.java:790
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:99
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:164
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:6528
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:438
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:807
```

I am assuming that the above app crash is taking place because of the infinite popups. Need some help regarding this.

Code snippet for Authrntication error:

```
private async void AuthenticationError(object sender, AuthenticatorErrorEventArgs e)
    {
            var authenticator = sender as OAuth2Authenticator;
            if (authenticator != null)
            {
                authenticator.Completed -= async (_sender, _e) => await AuthenticationCompleted(_sender, _e);
                authenticator.Error -= AuthenticationError;
            }

    }
```

Comment: I think you should find out why there are infinite popups?  Are you request Authentication infinitely?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Eventhough I am unsubscribing from the error event handler, still the popup keeps coming. Also, I am not requesting authentication infinitely. Similar to what has been mentioned in this post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5866/xamarin-auth-and-infinite-error-alerts

Comment: Did you try to add `authenticator.OnCancelled();`?